# drupal 7 taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load did not show the fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I have created a vocabulary and listed terms within it, in D7. I have added a field named "Icon Color". Now, within the view, I have added the code block as below which perfectly displayed the fields like tid, name, description but it did not show the field "Icon Color".

```
<?php
   $name = 'Programme';
   $myvoc = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($name);
   $tree = taxonomy_get_tree($myvoc->vid);
   foreach ($tree as $term) { 
   print_r($term); 
   }
?>
```

The fields are listed within the vocabulary as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must load the taxonomy using term id by taxonomy term load function. Hope the below code helps you.

```
$name = 'YOUR_MACHINE_NAME';
$myvoc = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($name);
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($myvoc->vid);
foreach ($tree as $term) { 
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($term->tid);
  print_r($term);
}
```